# Multiple windows in WPF and the ability to tile them

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am writing a terminal in WPF, which communicates the host with an embedded device through RS232.
I want to be able to open multiple connections that will reside on different tabs, I believe that for that purpose WPF's tabContorl is sufficient, However the customer wants to be able to tile the different tabs on the screen, and as I understand the basic tabControl doesn't allow you to do that.

Any ideas how can this be done?

any help will be appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's overkill, but I would give a try to [Avalon Dock from the WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AvalonDock&referringTitle=Home), it's free. With that, you will be able to move terminals around, dock them wherever you wish and even have only opened at a time if you unpin others.

[image]

Comment: (My full comment)First of all thank you for taking the time. I'll probably gonna use the AvalonDock, But I was wondering do you know another recommendation for a third party control (not necesseraly free). plus I am looking for a simple example just to get me started.. if you have a good reference it will be great.  tnx.

Comment: Check http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/overview.aspx if there's something similar like AvalonDock. As for the example, there's one at http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AvalonDock&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 1):

I have made a custom WPF control called [`ModalContentPresenter`](https://github.com/BenjaminGale/ModalContentPresenter) that allows you to display modal content which I think will be suitable. The control allows you to conditionally display additional content on top of your primary content.

Your application window will comprise a single `ModalContentPresenter` which will contain your `TabControl` in it's primary content and an `ItemsControl` in it's modal content.

```
<c:ModalContentPresenter IsModal="{Binding IsTiling}">

    <DockPanel>
        <Button Content="Show tiled view" 
                Command={Binding ShowTiledViewCommand}
                DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Connections}"> />
    </DockPanel>

    <c:ModalContentPresenter.ModalContent>
        <DockPanel>
            <Button Content="Hide tiled view" 
                    Command={Binding HideTiledViewCommand}
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
            <Itemscontrol ItemsSource="{Binding Connections}" />        
        </DockPanel>
    </c:ModalContentPresenter.ModalContent>

</c:ModalContentPresenter>
```

- By default the modal content will not be displayed so all the user will see is the `TabControl`.
- Both the `TabControl` and `ItemsControl` are bound to the same collection of data in your viewModel ensuring that the tiled view is in sync with the items in the tab control.
- Your viewModel must have a `Boolean` property called `IsTiling` which should return `true` when you want the 'tiled' view to be shown and `false` when it is hidden.
- When the tiled view is displayed users will be unable to interact with the primary content.
- You can change the layout panel used by the `ItemsControl` to change how the collection of data is 'tiled'.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25821197/577417) answer for an additional example of how to use the control.

The interface of your viewModel will look something like this:

```
public interface ViewModel {
    public ObservableCollection<Connection> Connections { get; }
    public boolean IsTiling { get; }
    public ICommand ShowTiledViewCommand { get; }
    public ICommand HideTiledViewCommand { get; }
}
```

Once you have this working you can add some additional enhancements to improve the look and feel of the user interface.

I would start by assigning a custom control template to the `TabControl` so that a `Button` is displayed in the 'header' area. This `Button` is bound to a command in your viewModel which is responsible for changing the `IsTiling` property to `true`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4705081/577417) question provides a link to an answer which explores ways of achieving this.

A second enhancement is to remove the button from the modal content and call the `HideTiledViewCommand` command when the user selects an item in the items control. You can then add some additional logic which selects the correct tab when the tiled view is closed. I think this can be achieved by having an additional property in your viewModel representing the selected connection.